# What is the specification need to be followed for SPI

Tags: spi, protocol

I dont think we have a standard specification for for SPI unlike CAN and LIN.
After Googling it found that motorola SPI and TI SPI are more commonly used but not able to find the referance documents
How do I get the motorola or TI SPI documentation so as to know the differences and their implementation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you don't start with "raw" SPI specification. Just look at your MCU datasheet or reference manual and see how its SPI peripheral operates.

The difference in the modes is the clock polarity and phase. [Have a look here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Clock_polarity_and_phase)

Most microcontrollers support all 4 modes, but the slave devices support only one or two, so the SPI mode is determined by the slave device. 99% of the time mode 0 is used.

Answer (score 0):

> to know the differences and their implementation

SPI has two facets:

1. hardware implementation - wires CS (SS), CLK, MOSI and MISO. However their names may slightly differ keeping the same functionality. Hardware design is well defined in how connections are made and how access to the bus is arbitrated;
2. protocol over the hardware connection - here're two more things:

   - clock polarity and phase (see filo's answer) - clock signal level when slave select goes active. These modes are also well defined, and your task is to ensure that slave supports the mode you drive it in;
   - data bits travelling from master to slave, and back - this, to my knowledge, is not standardized. Actually standardization of the contents is not required, and it is up to master and slave using any protocol (or language) when master activates slave through its CS (SS) signal. To know specific bit sequence to handle slave, and its command set, you must read its datasheet and design (or use) master appropriately.